# How do I display pagination in Yii2 GridView?

Tags: php, yii2, kartik-v, yii2-active-records

I am getting my dataProvider from which I try to remove some models that don't meet the wanted criteria. This filter is not SQL related and therefore I can't apply it directly to the query. On my view the pagination links are displayed if I leave the dataprovider just as it was. But after I apply the filters to remove the unwanted models, the pagination links disappear. I have tried setting the pagination on my new dataProvider but nothing works.

Here's my code in the controller action:

```
 $request = Yii::$app->request;
    $search_model = new StaffEmploymentListViewSearch();
    $data_provider = $search_model->search($request->queryParams);

    $models = $data_provider->models;
    for($k=0;$k<count($models);$k++)
    {
        if($models[$k]->employ === null){
            unset($models[$k]);
        }
    }
  
    $config = [
        'pageParam' => 'page',
        'pageSizeParam' => 'per-page',
        'forcePageParam' => true,
        'route' => null,
        'params' => null,
        'urlManager' => null,
        'validatePage' => true,
        'totalCount' => 5214,
        'defaultPageSize' => 20,
        'pageSizeLimit' => [
            '0' => 1,
            '1' => 50
        ],
        'pagesize' => 20
    ];
 
    $data_provider->setModels($models);
    $data_provider->setPagination($config);

    return $this->render('all-staff',[
        'dataProvider' => $data_provider,
        'searchModel' => $search_model
    ]);
```

Here's my search method:

```
$query = StaffEmploymentListView::find()
            ->SELECT([
                'PAYROLL_NO', 
                'BIRTH_DATE',
                "ADD_MONTHS(BIRTH_DATE, 70 * 12) AS RETIRE_DATE"
            ]);
    
    // add conditions that should always apply here
    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
        'sort' => false,
        'pagination' => [
            'pagesize' => 20,
        ],
    ]);
```

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: Can you provide the sql what you trying to implement, Also why you not just use sql queries to remove from the begging thous models which has employ status equal to `null`? Can you provide your search method?

Comment: @SergheiLeonenco my filter is not sql related.

Comment: To better help you show your `search` method.

Comment: @SergheiLeonenco I have edited the question to include the search method.

Comment: 1) May be you have less than 20 records?

2) Try `pageSize` instaed of `pagesize` (capital letter S)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `ArrayDataProvider`

```
    $query = StaffEmploymentListView::find()
            ->select([
                'PAYROLL_NO', 
                'BIRTH_DATE',
                "ADD_MONTHS(BIRTH_DATE, 70 * 12) AS RETIRE_DATE"
            ]);
    
    $allModels = [];
    foreach ($query->all as $staffEmployment)
    {
        if ($model->employ === null){
            $allModels[] = $model;
        }
    }

    $dataProvider = new ArrayDataProvider([
        'allModels' => $allModels,
        'pagination' => [
            'pageSize' => 20,
        ],
        'sort' => false
    ]);

    return $this->render('all-staff',[
        'dataProvider' => $data_provider,
        'searchModel' => $search_model // ???
    ]);
```